# Post and retrieve MySQL data from PHP into html with request

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

First of all I want to note that I am very new with `HTML` and `PHP`, `JS` and web design at all, but I have to learn and create registration form for my personal page, and should find out with proper approach and possible method.

I have `index.php` with user login and registration forms. Inside `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body> ... </body></html>` login form includes `input type="text"` and `type="password"`:

```
<div id="loginWrap">
 <div class="container">
  <form action="login.php" method="post" id="logform">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="fname">Username:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="yuser" name="username" placeholder="Username.." required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="lname">Password:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="password" id="ypass" name="password" placeholder="Password.." required>
      </div>
    </div>
  <br/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="lname"></label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" id="logBtn">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

sends `name="username"` to `PHP` with `action="login.php"` in `<Form>`, which was separate `login.php` code document used this way from `index.html`. Now it is included to `index.php` just as it was separately, without any edit:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, md5($_POST["password"]));

  $SQL = "INSERT INTO registration (username, password) VALUES ('$Username', '$Password')";  
  if (!mysqli_query($con, $SQL))
  {
      echo 'Not Inserted';
  }
  else
  {
     echo 'Inserted';
  }      
?>
```

How to pass inserted `name="username"` and `name="password"` to `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` in same `index.php` page with press on `<input type="submit" value="Login" id="logBtn">` and avoid processing of this code with `index.php` page loading automatically.

Any guide, explanation or advice would be very helpful

Comment: not getting what you want to achieve.

Comment: you can use AJAX for the same.

Comment: **Warning!** Don't use md5 for password hashing! [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) even states: _"Warning - It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm"_. You should use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a secure hash. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: @Pathik Vejani Hello, thank you for feedback! Include `html` and `php` code in  `index.php`, record inserted `name="username"` and `name="password"` to `MySQL` and retrieve `PHP` echo inside this page.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Hello! Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @Lado_O I think you want data retrieval without refreshing the page. is it?

Comment: @Pathik Vejani Yes, exactly

Comment: @ladoo111 then use AJAX.

Comment: Also, see about prepared and bound queries

Comment: try to find how ajax can be useful to you

Comment: @Lado_O let me know what exactly you want? Like you want username after submitting data?

Comment: @Pathik Vejani Seems like AJAX is what I actually need, thank you for your advice

Comment: @Lado_O I am posting answer.

Comment: @Strawberry Hello, thanks for the advice on [PHP Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: @Lado_O see the answer with `AJAX` implementation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AJAX` to achieve this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="loginWrap">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
          <label for="fname">Username:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
          <input type="text" id="yuser" name="username" placeholder="Username.." required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
          <label for="lname">Password:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
          <input type="password" id="ypass" name="password" placeholder="Password.." required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
          <label for="lname"></label>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="logBtn">
      </div>
  </div>
```

**AJAX:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $("#logBtn").click(function() {
      var uname = $("#yuser").val();
      var pass = $("#ypass").val();
      if(uname == '') {
        alert('Please enter username.')
      } else if (pass == '') {
        alert('Please enter password.')
      } else {
        $.ajax ({
          url: 'login.php',
          data: {username: uname, password: pass},
          type: 'post',
          success: function(result)
          {
            // here you will get result
            console.log(result);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
```

**Login.php:**

```
require 'connect.php';
  if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, md5($_POST["password"]));
    if($uname == '' || $pwd == '') {
      echo 'Please enter required information';
    } else {
      $query = "INSERT INTO registration (username, password) VALUES ('$uname', '$pwd')";
      if (!mysqli_query($con, $query))
      {
        echo $uname." cannot be registered! Please try again.";
        <!-- echo 'Not Inserted'; -->
      }
      else
      {
        // instead of msg you can return username like below:
        echo $uname." registered successfully!";
        // echo 'Inserted';
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Something is wrong!';
  }
```

Comment: I've added your `HTML`, `AJAX` `JS` code in `index.php`, and I've tried as include your `PHP` externally as `url: 'login.php'`, in `index.php` and inside `index.php` as `url: 'index.php'` for own self, as it works with _shihab_ statement. Inside 'index.php' 'I've used statement, with external `login.php` I've tried both, but nothing with `console.log(result);` or `document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = result;` with AJAX. Please, confirm if your example means adding 'login.php' separately from 'index.php' and check if nothing is missed in your example

Comment: @Lado_O yes, there should be separate file `login.php` in which you have `insert` statement

Comment: `HTML` and `AJAX` code will be in `index.php` file and `insert` statement will be in `login.php` file

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong here: `connect.php` works  with previous login or anything else. I did not changed anything in your `login.php` except removing of comment  `<!-- echo 'Not Inserted'; -->`, `AJAX` included to `<script type="text/javascript">` with `url: 'login.php`', HTML login code matches all values without edit, but I don't have record and `console.log(result);` or `document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = result;` from does not gives anything. I want figure out with your answer, because separated `.php`-s seems to me  useful, but by some reason it does not works

Comment: check `login.php` getting data or not by debugging

Comment: with statement `Something is wrong!` of course, without statement `Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\folder\login.php on line 4 Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\folder\login.php on line 5 Please enter required information`, but password and username is correct and successfully passes with previous method (without `AJAX`) as with separate `.php` also with included.

Comment: @Lado_O I have edited `AJAX` to `data: {username: uname, password: pass},` Please check. Removed `"`

Comment: checking `login.php` with direct load gives error, because nothing is there I guess, also I have edited `$_POST["password"]` to `$_POST['password']` if double quotes can cause failure, and  as you suggested changed `data: {"username": uname, "password": pass}` to  `data: {username: uname, password: pass}`, but it is same result, nothing. Did you have tried this code on your machine?

Comment: So, all is correct, problem was with `#logBtn`, which was given twice in HTML. Thank you very much for your attentive support and great example, I will remark your answer, because my goal is retrieve  data without refreshing the page and use separated .php-s

Comment: @Lado_O Ok. No problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just check for if the submitted value is present . then run the query.

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

if( isset( $_POST['username'] ) && isset( $_POST['password'] )  ){

$Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, md5($_POST["password"]));

  $SQL = "INSERT INTO registration (username, password) VALUES ('$Username', '$Password')";  
  if (!mysqli_query($con, $SQL))
  {
      echo 'Not Inserted';
  }
  else
  {
     echo 'Inserted';
  }      
} 


?>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but If you just help us to make it a habit of using prepared statements instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string` I will be happy by upvoting this answer :)

Comment: @shihab Hello, thank you for your answer, it works fine, but I will remark it to  _Pathik Vejani_  answer, because my goal is retrieve data without refreshing the page and use separated .php-s